# special characters removal from text file using U-SQL

Tags: c#, u-sql

Can you please help me to remove the `Special Character(”)` from a text file using `U-SQL`.

```
@testResult = 
    SELECT Card_no, 
    Regex.Replace(Card_no, "s+|\\'|\\”", "9999") AS var4
    FROM @testData;
```

getting the syntax error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@testResult = 
    SELECT Card_no, 
    Card_no.Replace("”", "9999") AS var4
    FROM @testData;
```